# Using yum module in ansible to install multiple versions of rpm

Tags: ansible, yum

I have an rpm of my application.
I'm using ansible to deploy and install the rpm on multiple services.
In case the rpm install fails, I want to keep only the previous rpm version that was installed. For example, if I install rpm v15 and afterwards v18 and v18 fails, I want to keep v15 and revert the changes of v18 install.

When using rpm I can easily install multiple versions of the same rpms with the following command :

```
rpm -ihv --oldpackage my-rpm-18.rpm
```

Is there a way to do it with yum module in ansible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to install the latest version in a `block` then use `rescue` to fall back on the desired version in case of error:

```
- block
    - yum:
        name: my-rpm
        state: latest
  rescue:
    - yum:
        name: my-rpm-18
        state: present
```

- [Ansible handling errors with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks)

Comment: Its a good solution but its not good enough. Yum removes the previous version, I dont want to remove it. I want to have at any time, 2 versions installed of my rpm.

Comment: If your fallback rpm is always the same version and you're sufficiently confident that package wouldn't fail, couldn't you just pass a list of the different versions you want installed? `name: [my-rpm-15, my-rpm17]`?

Comment: I dont want to reinstall the previous version, I want to keep 2 versions at any time..